# Does CDO / MAPI still working with Exchange 2013?

Tags: email, exchange-server, vb6-migration, mapi, cdonts

I have an old VB application that send mail this way using a Mapi.Session

```
Set objSession = New mapi.Session
strProfileInfo = strServeurExchange & vbLf & strSender_I
objSession.Logon NewSession:=True, NoMail:=False, ShowDialog:=False, ProfileInfo:=strProfileInfo
```

Now our exchange server will be Upgrade from 2008 to 2013.  Does my App will still be able to connect and send mail? If not how can I convert It?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of MAPI CDO update that now work with E2013. The most recent is the May 2013 update which can be found here: [Microsoft Exchange Server MAPI Client and Collaboration Data Objects 1.2.1 May 2013 Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39045)

As Dmitry mentioned, you will need to use ROH though.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not work. CDO 1.21 is not aware of RPC-over-HTTP connections (ROH) and creates a temporary profile without using ROH, which is the only kind of connection accepted by Exchange 2013.

You might be able to use Redemption for that  - the upcoming version of Redemption will support RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox with ROH connections.